# Is it possible to use TM1 as a data source for Analysis Services?

Tags: ssas, cognos-tm1

We have a finance department who are addicted to TM1, but are otherwise moving from Cognos to SSAS. Does anyone know if we can use TM1 as a data source? Is it difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look for an ETL-Tool like Cubeware Importer, which allows to read/write SSAS and Cognos TM1 in both directions:
http://en.cubeware.de/products/cubeware-product-portfolio/cubeware-importer.html
This will serve the needs of your financial department and the IT department as well.

--
Elmar Schiffelholz
Mandora Business Solutions, Munich, GERMANY
IBM Business Partner
Cubeware Certified Partner
www.mandora.de

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do you can use conversion software that will extract the TM1 schema and data and place this in SQL Server tables and create cubes directly off this. The Analysis Services cubes can be made writeable and thus your users can do what they want in TM1 but in Analysis Services.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done through tm1 itself. You would have to create ti processes of data dump which you need for reporting... As csv. This then can be scheduled as per time which you want. This can be fully automated

Comment: rather than this kind of explanation, please provide a good example or code snippet proofing your solution. so the other members in this community can get help. please read help guide:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer